Composer install of ESR using private token
Is there a way to manage a CiviCRM ESR instance based on Composer, using a gitlab-token?
I followed the instructions given by the esr-repo-https example. However there is no mention of the gitlab-token authentification way.
The Composer config is as follows:
[repositories.esr-drupal-8.url] https://lab.civicrm.org/esr/drupal-8.
[repositories.esr-packages.url] https://lab.civicrm.org/esr/packages.git
[repositories.esr-core.url] https://lab.civicrm.org/esr/core.git
[allow-plugins.civicrm/composer-compile-plugin] true
[allow-plugins.civicrm/composer-downloads-plugin] true
[allow-plugins.civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin] true
[gitlab-domains] [gitlab.com, https://lab.civicrm.org/esr/]
[gitlab-token.https://lab.civicrm.org/esr/] < PRIVATE TOKEN >

Instead of using the gitlab token, Composer keeps asking to authenticate using credentials:
Authentication required (lab.civicrm.org):
  Username:

PS: I already use this gitlab-token to handle a non Composer install.

It is described in the docs but it's in the examples/feeds one. It's just
composer config gitlab-domains lab.civicrm.org
composer config gitlab-token.lab.civicrm.org 'your-token'

P.S. I don't think the note about problems with composer v2 is still true.
